# How do I know what is the size limit for constructing a Set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a tool for deleting geometry from a model in browser.

At some step of the deletion process, I take an array full of indexes and create a Set from it to get the array of unrepeated indexes.

```
function GetSetFromArray(array){
    return new Set(array);
}
```

This function has worked good for many models at the beginning. Since I want to process the deletion as fast as possible, I wanted to avoid using solutions that require .indexOf.

But when I try to delete from a big model, for example, an array with a length of roughly 15,000,000. I get the following error on the browser's console:

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Set maximum size exceeded

[image: console error screenshot]

I want to know, what is the maximum size for creating a Set?
Is it something that depends on the Browser? Or on the PC running the Browser? Is there a way to get that number? I think that maybe if I could get the size limit of the Set, I could then split the array to make a series of Sets and then use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collection containing the items in a Set is called a "List" in the specification, and a limit on the size of a List is [not specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).

> These sequences may be of any length

Nor is the size of Set lists in particular specified. ([1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-iterable), [2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set.prototype.add))

> 3. Set set.[[SetData]] to a new empty List.

So, it must be implementation-defined.

> Is it something that depends on the Browser? Or on the PC running the Browser?

It will depend on the JavaScript engine the browser uses (for example, V8, or SpiderMonkey, or JavaScriptCore, among others).

> Is there a way to get that number?

Just `.add` items to a Set until it throws.

```js
const getSetSizeLimit = () => {
  let i = 0;
  const set = new Set();
  while (true) {
    try {
      set.add(i);
    } catch(e) {
      return i;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return i;
};
console.log(getSetSizeLimit());
```

On my Windows-Chrome, the limit looks to be 16777216, which is `2 ** 24`.

Comment: Can you explain how this script triggers the issue described by OP? Are you supposed to throw out the created set, I thought the goal was to get the OOM? The script just finished for me with a value of `67108863`, but what does that mean? This is on Linux - Firefox. Maybe the script should start at zero and keep creating sets with sizes which are powers of two until it can't anymore?

Comment: @smac89 same question. I guess it's an OS or browser or both thing, because I get the same result as CertainPerformance on Windows-Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to confirm the point at which the 'Set maximum size exceeded' happens. On OSX/Chrome I can create a Set from an array with length of up to 16,777,216.